# How can I offer a html for C++ to print in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, c++, css, angularjs

1. I'm on a angular app with c++ colleagues
2. We use google `cef` project to develop windows desktop project
3. This app can print resume which can be customed by a rich text editor(I use textAngular)
4. My C++ colleagues will handle the printing feature and need me to offer the html and the styles or images or pdf so they can print it.

Here is my question:

How can I get the html with inline styles in angularjs?

I can get html in my controller use `$('.resume').html()` but how can i deal with the styles?

By the way I use bootstrap grid system to layout the resume and some external stylesheets.

PS: Days before I use `html2canvas` to generate a image but it seems not support some styles and does not look like the original resume.

Comment: Maybe this? https://github.com/Karl33to/jquery.inlineStyler

Comment: Thanks @JesseBuitenhuis, I now use html2canvas to generate a png and give it to my colleagues, That plugin works fine too!